# OpenSSL Code Review

Tags: openssl, code-review

Is there to be a review in the code of OpenSSL any time in the near future? It seems OpenBSD is doing a controversial one, in that the review is also "Ripping out some windows-specific cruft". But is any actual security firm doing a code review, or are there plans by the OpenSSL project to hire one?

Comment: It appears the answer is yes (https://blog.bugcrowd.com/open-letter-to-internet-users-and-businesses/)

Comment: Maybe those guys will take care of it in a similar manner as truecrypt has been audited https://opencryptoaudit.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenBSD folks have started an [OpenSSL code review](http://opensslrampage.org/) recently, after which they decided to **fork OpenSSL into [LibreSSL](http://www.libressl.org/)**. Their changes to the code can be followed [here](http://freshbsd.org/search?project=openbsd&q=file.name%3alibssl).

As of last week, the major changes were:

> - [Remove OpenSSL’s bzero implementation](http://opensslrampage.org/post/82973015243/openssl-thought-that-they-were-clever-enough-to)
> - [Fix use after free](http://www.tedunangst.com/flak/post/analysis-of-openssl-freelist-reuse)
> - [Removed bad wrapper for issetugid](http://opensslrampage.org/post/82974142244/man-openssl-tried-so-hard-for-portability-but-just)
> - [Remove use of incorrect snprintf implementation](http://opensslrampage.org/post/82974271911/if-youre-going-to-reimplement-libc-functions-at-least)
> - [Remove memcmp and strncasecmp reimplemetations](http://opensslrampage.org/post/82974414915/memcmp-and-strncasecmp-are-just-like-malloc-too-slow)
> - [Stop seeding the entropy pool with time](http://opensslrampage.org/post/82975103611/so-the-openssl-codebase-does-get-the-time-add-it)
> - [Stop seeding the RNG with private key information](http://opensslrampage.org/post/83007010531/well-even-if-time-isnt-random-your-rsa-private-key)
> - [Removed custom gethostbyname](http://opensslrampage.org/post/83222773842/writing-your-own-dns-caching-functions-smells-like)
> - [Beginnings of Y2038 fixes](http://opensslrampage.org/post/83320780676/no-one-will-use-openssl-beyond-2038)
> - Tons and tons of VMS/MacOS 9/Windows code removal
> - KNF format the whole source tree (jsing)